# DIV width automatic with CSS?

Tags: css, html

I have 3 columns with divs, the middle one has fixed size 977px,
Left and Right one have no width, Im trying to set them automatic to have size equal to max window size - middle div size (977px) and devided by 2. So the left and right one are the same size.
Is there any way to do that.

Comment: You could make 2 container div, with max size, and inner div's make on %.

Comment: Since you tagged "CSS3", will you be satisfied with [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)?

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible without the calc() function introduced in CSS3. like  width:calc(100% - 400px);

Answer (score 1):

Are u looking like this ?

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="mid"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#container {
    width: 100%;
}

#mid {
    width: 977px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: red;    
    height: 100px;
}
```

[TEST](http://jsfiddle.net/b85EE/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same class style for them and set a common size for them if you want

like this:

```
<div id="container>
    <div id="left" class="outerdivs"></div>
    <div id="mid"></div>
    <div id="right" class="outerdivs"></div>
</div>
```